# Keep Original Format of MomentJS Date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

There are a lot of information about `moment().format()`, but none that I can find on what I am looking to do.

I have users entering in a date in any kind of format. I am looking to have moment add a number of days and then output the result in the original format.

Example:

```
var user1 = "2021-01-05";
var user2 = "01/05/2021";
var nextDate1 = moment(user1).add(1,'days');
var nextDate2 = moment(user2).add(1,'days');
```

Desired output for `nextDate`: `user1="2021-01-06"` and `user2="01/06/2021"` 
Actual Output of `nextDate` for both users are: `"Wed Jan 06 2021 00:24:00 GMT-0600"`

As mentioned the format can vary so I would like some way of either detecting the original format or if moment has this built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Moment.js (version 2.10.7+), you can use the Creation Data API.

```
moment(date).creationData().format
```

For the above case, you can create a wrapper function around the moment something like

```
const addDate = function (date) {
   const m = moment(date).add(1,'days');
   return m.format(m.creationData().format);
}

addDate(user1)
```

In cases where it won't be able to get the format, it would use the default format